# Mule Logging for sensitive Data

Tags: logging, mule, mule-component

I am Logging the Request Json Message on Mule and it is showing all the information as i m using to print the complete Payload. How can i mask or Hide sensitive data from the Mule Logger

```
   <logger message="Loin Request,#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Request Input"/>
```

Sample Request:

```
    {
  "credentials": {
    "userId": "test1234@yopmail.com",
    "password": "test12345"
  },
  "sessionID": 1234567890,
  "includecheckout": true
}
```

I am expecting to print in the log as below.

```
{
  "credentials": {
    "userId": "test1234@yopmail.com",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "sessionID": 1234567890,
  "includecheckout": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is possible, you can encrypt that particular field of JSON using Mule security module plugin which is an enterprise feature.
You need to use `<encryption:encrypt/>` component to encrypt the element in the JSON payload after placing `<json:json-to-object-transformer/>` which will help you to break the json into object and select the particular element to encrypt.
You can refer here to do this :-   http://bushorn.com/encrypting-a-json-element/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse and replace sensitive fields, or only extract fields that you want to log. Alternatively if your payload is set to a HashMap (or Expando) you can just log the fields you want by setting the Logger value using MEL like so:

`#[new [NotSensitiveField1: payload.NotSenstiveField1, NotSensitiveField2 : payload.NotSenstiveField2]]`

It may also pay to extrapolate this into a Java function and call it from within MEL (ie `#[com.LogFields.NoSensitiveFields(payload)]`) and encrypt or replace them with static data (ie "HIDDEN").